# On migration, why does the revision history disappear?

Tags: support, migration, revisions-list, migrated-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrated questions / answers should keep their full edit history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96398/migrated-questions-answers-should-keep-their-full-edit-history)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386830/php-script-not-returning-a-variable) has been migrated [from Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/posts/362429/revisions)
[image]

[to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9386830/revisions).
[image]

On Server Fault, the user [edited the title and tags](https://serverfault.com/posts/362429/revisions#rev1f0fd159-bb8b-460d-b653-b3a247ccaa4d). This didn't show up in the revision history on Stack overflow, however.

What's going on here?