# Does a migration remove edits from the edit history?

Tags: discussion, migration, revisions-list

According to [D.W.](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/5038/d-w), someone else edited [this answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/19950/6973) before it was migrated.

However, when I go to the edit history, I only see 2 versions, which corresponds to only his edit.

Does migration remove prior edits from the edit history?

Is there anything else that might have removed such an edit?

Answer (score 1):

Kind of yes, kind of no. The older revisions are not destroyed and are still present on the original (albeit deleted) answer on the source site. However, migration only transfers the *current* version of each post to the destination site. So the new site would only have one revision of each post, as if they had never been edited.

Comment: Isn't that a violation of the license under which the editor grants the content of their edit? The license requires attribution, but if the destination site doesn't show the editor and the source has deleted the answer, there's no attribution.

Comment: It's certainly a valid point to bring up, but I don't believe *editors* are afforded the same rights to attribution. I believe it only covers the actual author of the post.

Comment: In practice that's how it seems, but the ToS only says "Subscriber Content", and says it's licensed under CC-SA, which requires attribution. Nothing excludes edits from attribution, except maybe the fact that the terms don't mention attribution for edits. Maybe I'll bring this up in a meta post tomorrow.

Comment: Editors are coauthors if they made a creative contribution (e.g. expanding an explanation, wrote a better title) but not if they made a purely technical contribution (e.g. correcting a spelling error, indented code). This cannot be determined automatically, so the safe default is to preserve their attribution. @JoshuaDwire [Migrated questions / answers should keep their full edit history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96398/migrated-questions-answers-should-keep-their-full-edit-history)

Comment: Just posted: [Does the migration of edited posts violate attribution requirements?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208904/197656)