# Are reputation points, earned from an edit, lost when the question is migrated?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, migration

If one makes an edit to someone else's question on one SE site (let's call it SE.A), and that edit is approved, the *editor* gains two reputation points, as we all know.  However, if that question is subsequently *migrated* to another site (let's call it SE.B), then the reputation points earned on SE.A are deducted, but do not seem to to be the re-earned on the site to which the question was migrated, i.e. SE.B, even if the editor is also a member of SE.B

This seems a little unfair, and would lead to one wanting to hang fire on the edit until *after* the migration has occurred. Granted this is possible if the question is *obviously* a misfit on the site to which it was originally posted. However, sometimes this is not immediately obvious. So, basically the upshot is that SE.B gets an improved version of the question for "free"..?

I have noticed this a couple of times on questions that I have edited in the passed. I have seen my points on SE.A deducted, as they should be, but they never seem to reappear on SE.B but unfortunately I have always been too busy to follow it up, to ensure that this is actually the case.

I'm sure this question must be a duplicate, as surely someone else must have wondered this before. I apologise if this is the case. I have had a look, but none of the questions I saw answered my query directly. The closest I saw was [Does a migration remove edits from the edit history?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208831/does-a-migration-remove-edits-from-the-edit-history?s=2%7C0.7877), which seems to back up my theory.

Case in point:

On SE.Computer Science

Awarded points

> [image: Awarded points]

Deducted Points

> [image: Deducted points]

Migrated to Stack Overflow, and looking at the edits of the "For loop" question, my edits are not listed, so I assume I lost the points, and that they were not migrated to SE.SO from SE.CS.

> [image: Edits after migration]

After examining my reputation on SE.SO I can confirm that on March 5 (the date of the migration) nor April 11 (the date I lost the points on SE.CS), did *not* I receive +2 reputation points.

> [image: SE.SO points]

TL;DR - If reputation points, earned from an edit, are lost when the question is migrated, then is this a bug?

Comment: Do you have a question you've edited as a sample?

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Not to hand no. I agree that the question would have been better if I had a concrete example, because as it currently stands, it just sounds as if I am fishing for a bug. I wish try to root out a question that I edited and which was subsequently migrated. However, don't hold your breath :-) Actually, I think that I have found a couple (from Computer Science to SO). I will update the question.

Comment: I think the points from the edit will be lost when the migration stub is deleted, not immediately when the question is migrated.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce: That is true. If it is rejected, the reputation remains (the post will be deleted eventually, and the rep would be lost then)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reputation will be lost as far as I can see. The reputation from edits aren't migrated along with the post.

Also, the reputation won't be lost instantly. It will only be lost if the original post is deleted. This can happen after the migration was accepted, and the original question is deleted. Or the migration has been rejected, and it is regularly deleted as part of the clean up.

You can see [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502893/) for example:

It has been [edited](https://cs.stackexchange.com/posts/43035/revisions) by [Rene](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/32348/rene?tab=reputation) on CS and after that it was migrated. The original post is still there on CS, and Rene still has the +2 reputation of the edit.

On SO, [there is no proof of the 'edit'](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30502893/revisions), it is just migrated as is. [Rene didn't get the +2 there.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene?tab=reputation) (you could argue about this one, since he has +2K, so he would never have it, but the missing edit seems enough 'proof')

Comment: But...I need to earn rep by suggesting edits...if you keep migrating those I'll never reach the top user list...

Comment: Ok, Thanks. It's a bit of a sobering thought to think that all that time was spent editing for free... Not that I am "only in it for the money", but lost recompense is always a bit galling... :-)

Comment: Then get 2K and you won't get reputation for an edit any more (unless it are tag wikis)