# How can we flag a migrated question?

Tags: support, flags, migrated-questions

Recent changes to question migrations [change how question history is displayed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96398/135887).  The link to the migration source site no longer leads to the question on the source site.  Instead, it now links to the revision history.

While that's an improvement, there's now a problem.  There is now no way to actually get to the question body on the source site.  From time to time, I've found myself needing to flag migrated questions.  Migrated question stubs aren't editable except by diamond mods.  This means that when a migrated question uses a [tag that should not exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139869/135887), the only way to have the tag removed (thus allowing it to be reaped) requires diamond moderator intervention.

So, other than pointing out [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22360866/revisions) here on Meta, how can I flag a migration stub now that we can't actually reach the question itself?

Comment: Migration stubs are deleted after 30 days - you don't really have to do anything special to them. Unless you're bored, I guess. But seriously: don't worry about these.

Comment: @Shog9 BTW: if automatic deletion applied also to [rejected migrations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224474/), users would not have to worry about those either.

Comment: Yeah - for now, flagging those and asking a moderator to delete them *is* useful, @127

Comment: @Shog9, with popular but low quality tags like `server`, even having it around for a few hours results in a half dozen questions added.  Just because I *have* 221 tags on my kill list, that doesn't mean I actually *like* editing dozens of questions a day.  Keeping the tag alive due to a migration stub for *thirty days* would probably push me off the deep end...

Comment: This should be taken care of now. I also retagged a few new questions to remove [server]. Do I need to do anything else to get rid of this tag?

Comment: Thank you, @BradLarson!  Unfortunately unless you can find an effective way to stop people from using it long enough for the nightly reaper to take care of it, there's not much else to be done.  Don't worry, it'll be back within a week or two.  It always is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the URL of "Return to Question" link at the top and append `?noredirect=1` to it. [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360866/how-can-i-safely-downgrade-from-php-5-5-to-5-4?noredirect=1).