# Does community wiki still have to be attributed?

Tags: discussion, support, community-wiki, attribution

If there is a community wiki post, does it come under the same attribution rules?

Or is there no need for me to link back to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does community wiki still have to be attributed?

Yes. Community Wiki status does not change attribution rules in any way.

You are required to follow attribution requirements for it, like for any other post.

What seems to be a bit unclear is which author to mention (given that CW posts tend to often be collaborative works).

<strike>Picking the original author (or if in doubt, the user the system displays as the author) seems like a fair compromise that is unlikely to ever get you in any trouble.</strike> Gilles argues [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208904/does-the-migration-of-edited-posts-violate-attribution-requirements/208952#208952) that *every author* with a substantial contribution to a post needs to be acknowledged.

Comment: Separate question: do the rules still apply within the network?

Comment: @Tim I don't see why not. Using content from another post in a SO answer without attribution will get you dinged for plagiarism.

Comment: @Pëkka better get editing. I'd linked back, but not included the author's name.

Comment: @Tim oooh, *that* I guess is not really a problem, even though it may not be following the letter of the law. Not within the network. I was writing in relation to not mentioning the original post at all.

Comment: @Pëkka phew, wasn't looking forward to spelling names + linking. I (personally) think the attribution is a little strict. I think I'll leave it, I've never been called out before.