# Questions migrated more than 60 days ago no longer link to their revision history on the origin site (possible license violation)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration, revisions-list, licensing

In January 2014, the migration banner on questions migrated from other sites was [changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216280/377214) to link to the revision history of the question on the origin site (the migration stub), and said revision history would be kept visible to all users even after the stub was deleted. This was done to comply with CC licensing requirements, since when a question is migrated, only its latest revision is moved to the new site, and there was no attribution supplied to users who edited the post on the original site.

Prior to that change, the migration banner simply linked to the stub question itself, with the `?noredirect=1` parameter.

However, as migration banners [are now hidden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339794/377214) on posts migrated from other sites more than 60 days ago, the link to this revision history is now gone again. The stub can still be accessed from the revision history, but the revision history item still links to the stub question itself (with the `?noredirect=1` parameter), not the revision history (i.e. what the banner *used* to link to prior to the change noted above).

While it's still possible to get to the stub's (always publicly visible) revision history, now it requires one to manipulate the URL after clicking the link. Also, the notice one receives upon following the link is (almost always) a 404, which misleadingly implies that the revision history isn't visible, even though it is. This therefore means that the license may possibly be violated since there is the attribution is now obfuscated.

Can this please be fixed? The easiest way to resolve this issue, without modifying the notice logic, is simply to make the revision history item link to the stub's revision history rather than the stub itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is now fixed.

For a post that has been migrated from another site, both the timeline and revisions page for the post will now give a link to the revisions page for the *MigratedFrom* post from the original site. This is in addition to the link to the *MigratedFrom* post as well that is currently displayed.

---

> a migrated post,
> whence did it originate?
> link to revisions

Comment: I found a bug in the implementation. On migrated answers, these revision links [go to the question's history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372072/links-to-migrated-answers-revision-histories-incorrectly-go-to-the-parent-quest) instead of the answer's history.

Comment: Did you see the comment, "I found a bug in the implementation. On migrated answers, these revision links [go to the question's history](see link in OP) instead of the answer's history." ?