# Links to migrated answers' revision histories incorrectly go to the parent question's revision history instead of the answer's history

Tags: bug, answers, migration, revisions-list

When a question along with its answers is migrated to another site, only its latest revision is copied to the destination site. Originally, there was no attribution supplied to users who edited either the question or its answers on the origin site before migration, so in January 2014 a [change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216280/377214) was made whereby the relevant revision history pages on the origin site would remain visible to the public even after the copies on the origin site were deleted.

Several years later, following [this feature request of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340812/377214), links to these revision histories on the origin site are now supplied in the history pages on the destination site of every migrated post (previously, these were only in the migration notice, which [began to be hidden 60 days post migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339794/377214) after the new post notice system rolled out).

This works absolutely fine for questions: the revision item on the destination site links back to the migration stub's history on the origin site. However, this doesn't work correctly for answers, as the link in the revision item links back to the parent question's history, not to the answer's history.

As an example, take [this answer's revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/22175/revisions). The answer was originally posted ID 135687 on Stack Overflow, posted to the question with ID 135685 there, but the "revisions" link incorrectly links to post 135685 instead of 135687 on SO:

[image: Revision history incorrect link]

The first link, to the answer itself with the `?noredirect=1` parameter correctly links to the origin answer on Stack Overflow. However, the "revisions" link incorrectly links to the parent question's revision history instead of the answer's history. (After manipulating the URL to the answer's ID, one can see the migrated answer's revision history even if they don't have enough reputation to see deleted posts.)

Can this please be fixed? I think it's important because this can be a violation of the license, since attribution to those who edited an answer on the origin site before it was migrated is effectively being obfuscated behind a URL change.